# WCF x509 Certificate Message Authentication works when built in VS 2019, but fails when self hosted

Tags: c#, wcf, x509certificate, self-hosting

I've created a WCF service and a simple forms application to access it. So far, prior to adding the certificate stuff, it was all working perfectly and I was able to get a return from the service successfully.

After experimenting with certificates, I've been able to update the configs in the client and service so that when built from visual studio, the application works perfectly fine using the certificates.

My issue is when using a self hosting console app to host the service outside of visual studio, I get a "Secure channel cannot be opened because security negotiation with the endpoint has failed. This may be due to absent or incorrectly specified EndpointIdentity in the EndpointAddress used to create the channel." error.

Just wondering if anyone can see any glaring errors in my configs that could be causing this? Like I said, it works when visual studio mounts the service, but something in the self hosting causes the error.

FYI: The client trace just says the error i said above. Server trace doesn't even show up. WCFTestClient also says the service is being hosted.

Cheers!

**Client:**

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                 switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                 propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData="c:\Client.svclog"  />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="endpointCredentialsBehavior">
            <clientCredentials>
              <clientCertificate findValue="TraceCert"
                                 storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                 x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            </clientCredentials>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="clientBinding">
                    <security>
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/ContactTraceWCF" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="clientBinding" contract="ContactTraceServer.IContactTraceServer"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IContactTraceWCF" behaviorConfiguration="endpointCredentialsBehavior">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="TraceRootCA" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Server:**

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                 switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                 propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "c:\Server.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ContactTraceWCF.ContactTraceServer">
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IContactTraceWCF"
                  contract="ContactTraceWCF.IContactTraceServer"
                  name="WSHttpBinding_IContactTraceWCF">
          <identity>
            <dns value="TraceRootCA" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ContactTraceWCF" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="TraceRootCA"
                                storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                                x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"/>
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IContactTraceWCF">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Host Console App:**

```
    using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ContactTraceServer), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/ContactTraceWCF")))
    {
        try
        {
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IContactTraceServer), new WSHttpBinding(), "");

            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            serviceHost.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            serviceHost.Close();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException timeProblem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(timeProblem.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException commProblem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(commProblem.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did the experiment according to your description. It is likely that your configuration file was not read by the service. This may be there is a problem with the location of your configuration file, which causes the service to fail to read your configuration file.

Comment: If the service can read the configuration file correctly, your server-side will not run at all, and it will report an error, because you have configured the address of serverhost in the configuration file .In the main program, you have configured his address again. Normally, it will report "this collection already contains an address with scheme http." error, but you don't seem to have.

Comment: You are right, the configuration file was not being read by the self host application. I'm not sure how to fix this, so I basically rewrote the config when building the service host for the self host application (As indicated by the answer I gave). This is only a mess around project, so it works as much as is required. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

So after some testing, I found that when creating the self host, it doesn't pull from the WCF service's app.config, so you have to basically rewrite it when building the servicehost.

I've provided the code below that worked for me.

```
    using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ContactTraceServer), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/")))
    {
        try
        {
            var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IContactTraceServer), binding, "ContactTraceWCF");
            serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "TraceRootCA");
            serviceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            serviceHost.Open();


            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            serviceHost.Close();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException timeProblem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(timeProblem.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException commProblem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(commProblem.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```